# Not able to overlay paint brush on Photoshop 2022

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush, clipping-mask

I am new to photoshop. Using `Photoshop 2022` latest update. I am learning it. Now the issue is (Not sure if it is an issue. Couldn't find any use full info on search)

- I opened an image
- Added a clipping mask
- Took the `Brush Tool` to paint some shadow
- Changed the Opacity to 6%
- Then painted on the `Clipping mask layer`

**Now if I paint over the already drawn line in the same stroke, it is not adding dark color to the line. But if I release the mouse and paint again, then the line is getting thicker**

I am adding the reference image here. All the options I changes are visible
[image]

Here the topmost shades I tried draw multiple times on the same stroke. But the lines having the same light appearance. But on the lower lines, I tried the mouse release and draw and the line getting thicker.

**Is there any way where I can draw thicker lines on same stroke overlay without release the mouse and draw again and again?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean a *heavier, darker* line rather than thicker. Thickness is dependent on brush width & pressure [if you have a Wacom or similar].

[image]

Your issue seems to be your brush setting. You have Opacity 6%, Flow 100%.
That means that your brush will almost instantly be painting the maximum opacity you have set - just 6%. Once that value is reached on any given stroke that's it: no amount of over-brushing is going to increase that beyond 6%. To increase the density you must start a new stroke.

If you want to be able to over-brush to make a darker stroke without lifting your brush, then you need to set your options the other way round. Low flow with higher opacity. That way as you brush you'll get light strokes, but you can go back over the same area to darken it. You may need a little trial & error to find the optimum values for any given circumstance.

Also - looking at those brush edges, you'd very probably benefit from a softer brush.

[image]

You can do that either in the brush drop menu, top left, or by using  <kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd>  +  <kbd>[</kbd>  or  <kbd>]</kbd>  to soften or harden (in four steps). I'd definitely go as soft as possible to paint in shadows.

Quick demo of both techniques - lower flow & softer edges…

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Let me try this once.